# AWS codebuild to list out s3 buckets of other account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

[image]I have my codebuild build sitting on **Account A** and s3 buckets on **Account B**. I tried to set up a trusted IAM STS role on **Account B** and policy on **Account A** to include the **Account B** IAM role, attached this policy to my codebuild service role. But still, my codebuild shows buckets on s3. Am I doing or configuring something wrong here?

**Role with trust relation on Account B**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
```

**policy on Account A**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::Account B:role/testcli"
        }
    ]
}
```

**CodeBuild BuildSpec.yml**

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    TF_VERSION: "0.12.28"

phases:
  install:
    commands:
#       install required binary
      - echo test
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo print s3 buckets
      - aws s3 ls

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo test1
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? The exact policies, iam roles, your buildspec.yml ?

Comment: @Marcin updated question with the requested info

Comment: Do you want to access a specific bucket in Acc B from your CodeBuild? If yes, then you can enable this using bucket policies.

Comment: @Marcin I think adding policy in bucket would probably work but if I have 10 accounts accessing that particular bucket I have to go and update bucket policy whenever there is a new account added

Comment: I see. Then you would have to explicitly assume role in your ` buildspec.yml. I can make an answer with extra details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your CodeBuild (CB) has permissions to `sts:AssumeRole`, in your `buildspec.yml` you have to **explicitly** assume the role in Acc B.

There are **two ways** in which you can do this.

- "Manually" call [assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) in your `buildspec.yml`. The call will return a set of temporary credentials. The credentials obtained can then be used to execute AWS CLI commands in Acc B from your CB.
- Setup AWS CLI credentials files as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html) or [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-cli.html) in your CB container for assuming the roles.

In both cases the CB service-role needs `sts:AssumeRole` permissions.

Comment: I'm getting an``` error An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.``` after modifying buildspec.yml to use ```sts:Assumerole```

Comment: ```pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo print s3 buckets
      - aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::Account B:role/testcli --role-session-name testx > cred.json
      - s=$(jq '.Credentials.AccessKeyId' cred.json)
      - y=$(jq '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' cred.json)
      - z=$(jq '.Credentials.SessionToken' cred.json)
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$s
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$y
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$z
      - aws s3 ls
      - echo $y``` Part of buildspec that's calling ```sts:Assumerole```

Comment: @patrick Could you please edit the question with new info?

Comment: I figured out the issues, while parsing the accessid and secretkey there quotes that has to been trimmed. I'm able to get the list of buckets on Account B